# How convert an xml-file to array working on ID as structure for it.

Tags: php, xml

Having a XML-File so formed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<archive>
    <book id="a">
      <chapter id="a.1">
        <paragraph id="a.1.1">string 1</paragraph>
        <paragraph id="a.1.2">string 2</paragraph>
        <paragraph id="a.1.3">string 3</paragraph>
      </chapter>    
    </book>    
    <book id="b">
      <chapter id="b.1">
        <paragraph id="b.1.1a">string 4</paragraph>
        <paragraph id="b.1.1b">string 5</paragraph>
      </chapter>    
      <chapter id="b.2">
        <paragraph id="b.2.1">string 6</paragraph>
      </chapter>    
    </book>    
</archive>
```

How i can convert it in an array so formed:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => string 1
                    [2] => string 2
                    [3] => string 3
                )

        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1a] => string 4
                    [1b] => string 5
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => string 6
                )
        )
)
```

**NOTE**: 
a) Array is based on ID (gerarchy-structured) take from all element of xml-file.
b) ID is alphanumeric and DOT define the "level / gerarchy" of the content.

Comment: Have you tried something yourself?

Comment: I have tried with simpleXML and domdoccument but i have getted some difficult for first part. About second part extracting ID with a split me not have difficult to make array. For it i use something as: $struct[$array[0]][$array[1]][$array[2]] where $array is defined as:  $array = explode(".", $ID).

Comment: What are you building the array for? Are you sure that you can not use the DOM directly? Building an array from the data means that you loose information and the possibility to use Xpath.

Comment: About extra information it not are important, into array is important about "content" associated to ID gerarchy structered. A problem was about tag inside "content" and it i have solved. but when i go to get value i have Always info as object when need get it as string.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick hack which works on your example.
Basically I search for all xml leafs or paragraphs and build the array. From those leafs I fetch the parent and the parents parent and get their ids.

If your xml is inside `$xml` this code should work:

```
$result = [];
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
foreach ((new DOMXPath($dom))->evaluate('//*[count(*) = 0]') as $node) {
    $chapterId = end(explode(".", $node->parentNode->getAttribute('id')));
    $bookId    = $node->parentNode->parentNode->getAttribute('id');

    if (!isset($result[$bookId])) {
        $result[$bookId] = [];
    }

    if (!isset($result[$bookId][$chapterId])) {
        $result[$bookId][$chapterId] = [];
    }

    $result[$bookId][$chapterId ][end(explode(".", $node->getAttribute('id')))] = $node->nodeValue;
}
var_dump($result);
```

Will output:

```
array (size=2)
  'a' => 
    array (size=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          1 => string 'string 1' (length=8)
          2 => string 'string 2' (length=8)
          3 => string 'string 3' (length=8)
  'b' => 
    array (size=2)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          '1a' => string 'string 4' (length=8)
          '1b' => string 'string 5' (length=8)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          1 => string 'string 6' (length=8)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, rows with "end(explode(..))" don't work. i try to solve it.

Comment: It's possible that this only works for php5.4 or greater. You can get around it by storing the result of `explode(...` and access it's last element.